# how to export dat in .iif format from asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

how to export data in .iif format from asp.net application ?

Comment: what is dat? what is .iif format? Please explain that for anyone to be able to answer.

Comment: .iif means INTUIT INTERCHANGE FORMAT, use in the quickbooks account software export/importing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/76293.aspx).

For example:

> `Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";`
>
> Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;
>   filename=SailBig.jpg");
>
> Response.TransmitFile(
>   Server.MapPath("~/images/sailbig.jpg")
>   );
>
> Response.End();
>
> This will cause a Open / Save As
>   dialog box to pop up with the filename
>   of SailBig.jpg as the default filename
>   preset.
>
> This of course assumes you're feeding
>   a file that already exists. If you
>   need to feed dynamically generated -
>   say an image that was generated in
>   memory - you can use
>   Response.BinaryWrite() to stream a
>   byte array or write the output
>   directly in Response.OutputStream.
>
> Bitmap bmp =
>   wwWebUtils.CornerImage(backcolor,
>   color, c, Radius, Height, Width);
>
> Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
>
> Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;
>   filename=LeftCorner.jpg");
>
> bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream,
>   ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Obviously you would just change the extension.